# Sinatra with Kaminari: cannot load such file -- kaminari/sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, kaminari

I want to realize pagination in Sinatra with kaminari. 
My Gemfile looks like this:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem "sinatra"
gem "activerecord", :require => "active_record"
gem "mysql2"
gem "padrino-helpers"
gem "kaminari", :require => "kaminari/sinatra"
```

my Sinatra config.ru has a `Bundler.require`.

However, Passenger displays the following error: `cannot load such file -- kaminari/sinatra`

I don't know what's wrong. There is not much documentation about kaminari with Sinatra, and the only bit i found was: "You need padrino-helpers and require kaminari/sinatra". And that's what i did.

Comment: Did you try to run the app not by `passenger`? And do you use `rvm`?

Comment: What version of kaminari have you got? (`bundle show kaminari`)

Comment: I am using rvm. The app does not start when i'm not using passenger, either.

Comment: I am using rvm. The app does not start when i'm not using passenger, either. `bundle show kaminari` says i have kaminari 0.11.0 installed. The rubygems.org page stated that 0.14 is the current version, so i required it explicitly in my Gemfile. But now, i have the next problem. Kaminari requires rack ~>1.2.1 and sinatra requires rack 1.5.2.

Comment: You will probably need to ask a new question to get your new issue resolved.

Comment: Only recent versions started supporting sinatra, so you shoud put something like `gem 'kaminari', '~>0.14.1', :require => 'kaminari/sinatra'` into your Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

Sinatra (~> 1.4.0) depends on rack (1.5.2), while kaminari (~> 0.13.0) depends on rack (~> 1.2.1). And since kaminari only began experimental support for Sinatra since version 0.13.0, there appears to be an impasse.